# Node.js using different listening port than assigned

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I set socket.io to listen to port 4000. When I view my app from my browser, the page will not load on port 4000. However, app will load on port 5500. Could not find where port 5500 was assigned.

```js
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = require('socket.io').listen(4000).sockets;
const dbName = 'chats'; //Database collection

// Connect to mongo
mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongochat', function(err, client) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

      console.log('MongoDB connected...');

      // Connect to Socket.io
      client.on('connection', function(socket) {
      let chat = client.db(dbName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Socket.io documentation ( https://socket.io/docs/server-api/ )

### Basic

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
```

### With options

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
  path: '/test',
  serveClient: false,
  // below are engine.IO options
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});
```

### ⚠️ Note

In case you are using some network package (like `express` or `http`), check that those packages are not overriding your listening port.

Comment: I am not using express or any other framework other than socket.io and mongodb. When I change to listening to port 5500, I get '404 (Not Found)' error.